# error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'vtkCommonCore-6.2.lib'

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2013, vtk

I'm trying to add vtk libraries in a qt project (using VS 2013). I add these like external libraries and in .pro file the resultant code is this:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/D:/VTK2/bin/lib/release/ -lvtkCommonCore-6.2
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/D:/VTK2/bin/lib/debug/ -lvtkCommonCore-6.2
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/D:/VTK2/bin/lib/ -lvtkCommonCore-6.2

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/D:/VTK2/install/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/D:/VTK2/install/include
```

When I run the program returns:

> error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'vtkCommonCore-6.2.lib'

Answer (score 0):

dont use $$PWD if u want to use absolute pathes. $$PWD is the path to your project file.

try:

INCLUDEPATH += D:/VTK2/install/include

LIBS += -LD:/VTK2/bin/lib/debug

LIBS += -lvtkCommonCore-6.2